# Rspec, how do I test if a response renders a template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm new to rspec and writing test. I need to write a test for the show action of my VideosController. Here is my test

```
describe VideosController do
  describe "GET show" do
    it "renders the show template" do
      video = Video.create(title: "Game of Thrones", description: "A very awesome show!")
      get :show, id: video.id
      expect(response).to render_template(:show)
    end
  end
end
```

When I run this I get this error

```
 1) VideosController GET show renders the show template
 Failure/Error: expect(response).to render_template(:show)
   expecting <"show"> but rendering with <[]>
```

What am I missing here?

EDIT: VideosController

```
class VideosController < ApplicationController

  before_action :require_user

  def show
    @video = Video.find(params[:id])
  end

  def search
    @search_phrase = params[:search_term]
    @search_result = Video.search_by_title(@search_phrase)
  end

  end
```

Comment: Your test looks fine to me. Can you post your controller code? Also you can use your logs to check for things like before_filters redirecting.

Comment: That's because *Game of Thrones* is not following any template at all..!

Comment: @agmcleod , your're right. I had a before_action in the VideosController and forgot about it. I updated my question. Now I have to figure out how to set the user.

Comment: @DougSteinberg what are you using for authentication, and `require_user`? You'll have to login in the `VideosController` spec

Answer (score 1):

For setting the user, controller tests are meant to be isolated from other aspects of the app. So really you can simply stub the user. Provided you're using a method in your application controller like:

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find session[:user_id]
end
```

Then you can just stub it:

```
controller.stub(current_user: User.create(email: "test@example.com", password: "abc123", password_confirmation: "abc123"))
```

Adjust the user params to your need. Also instead of invoking active record directly, have a look at: http://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl.

So what happens there is when the controller invokes current_user, it returns the user record.

Comment: That's almost exactly how my app looks. Thanks. The only thing that's new to me here is `controller.stub`. What does that do?

Comment: `controller` is a special helper method rspec gives us. It's an instance of the current controller. `stub` is a method you get that you can call on any object in an rspec test. Basically you're re-writing a method's return value. So if you have: `controller.stub(current_user: user)`, current_user will always return the user object instead of executing its logic.